# mobile social media icons not sizing correctly

Tags: responsive-design, icons

Website: http://wearetechnology.com/

We have custom social media icons in the header and the footer of the above site.

Everything looks fine on the computer, even when I resize the browser window but when we pull up the site on a smart phone the icons resize to different sizes (skinny, smaller, etc.).

We'd like them to stay the same size as on the regular site but I can't seem to find the correct area in CSS that is changing.

Here is the CSS that I am using:

```
.social-networks .facebook a{background-image:url(images/facebook-wat.png) !important; width:32px !important; height:32px !important;}
.social-networks .twitter a{background-image:url(images/twitter-wat.png) !important; width:32px !important; height:32px !important;}
.social-networks .linkedin a{background-image:url(images/linkedin-wat.png) !important; width:32px !important; height:32px !important;}
.social-networks .google a{background-image:url(images/google-wat.png) !important; width:32px !important; height:32px !important;}
```

I have added to the media.css file but nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you added this in your html head ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```